# How to streamline and speed up loop with getData package in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to download high-resolution climate data for a bunch of lat/long coordinates, and combine them into a single dataframe.  I've come up with a solution (below), but it will take forever with the large list of coordinates I have. I asked a related [question on the GIS StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389513/how-to-download-and-merge-0-5-minute-worldclim-data-for-a-long-list-of-coordin) to see if anyone knew of a better approach for downloading and merging the data, but I'm wondering if I could somehow just speed up the operation of the loop?  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do that?  Here is a reproducible example:

```
# Download and merge 0.5 minute MAT/MAP data from WorldClim for a list of lon/lat coordinates
# This is based on https://emilypiche.github.io/BIO381/raster.html

# Make a dataframe with coordinates
coords <- data.frame(Lon = c(-83.63, 149.12), Lat=c(10.39,-35.31))

# Load package
library(raster)

# Make an empty dataframe for dumping data into
coords3 <- data.frame(Lon=integer(), Lat=integer(), MAT_10=integer(), MAP_MM=integer())

# Get WorldClim data for all the coordinates, and dump into coords 3
for(i in seq_along(coords$Lon)) {
  r <- getData("worldclim", var="bio", res=0.5, lon=coords[i,1], lat=coords[i,2]) # Download the tile containing the lat/lon
  r <- r[[c(1,12)]] # Reduce the layers in the RasterStack to just the variables we want to look at (MAT*10 and MAP_mm)
  names(r) <- c("MAT_10", "MAP_mm") # Rename the columns to something intelligible
  points <- SpatialPoints(na.omit(coords[i,1:2]), proj4string = r@crs) #give lon,lat to SpatialPoints
  values <- extract(r,points)
  coords2 <- cbind.data.frame(coords[i,1:2],values)
  coords3 <- rbind(coords3, coords2)
}

# Convert MAT*10 from WorldClim into MAT in Celcius
coords3$MAT_C <- coords3$MAT_10/10
```

**Edit:** Thanks to advice from Dave2e, I've first made a list, then put intermediate results in the list, and rbind it at the end.  I haven't timed this yet to see how much faster it is than my original solution.  If anyone has further suggestions on how to improve the speed, I'm all ears!  Here is the new version:

```
coordsList <- list()
for(i in seq_along(coordinates$lon_stm)) {
  r <- getData("worldclim", var="bio", res=0.5, lon=coordinates[i,7], lat=coordinates[i,6]) # Download the tile containing the lat/lon
  r <- r[[c(1,12)]] # Reduce the layers in the RasterStack to just the variables we want to look at (MAT*10 and MAP_mm)
  names(r) <- c("MAT_10", "MAP_mm") # Rename the columns to something intelligible
  points <- SpatialPoints(na.omit(coordinates[i,7:6]), proj4string = r@crs) #give lon,lat to SpatialPoints
  values <- extract(r,points)
  coordsList[[i]] <- cbind.data.frame(coordinates[i,7:6],values)
}

coords_new <- bind_rows(coordsList)
```

**Edit2:** I used system.time() to time the execution of both of the above approaches.  When I did the timing, I had already downloaded all of the data, so the download time isn't included in my time estimates.  My first approach took 45.01 minutes, and the revised approach took 44.15 minutes, so I'm not really seeing a substantial time savings by doing it the latter way.  Still open to advice on how to revise the code so I can improve the speed of the operations!

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/389513/115

Comment: You need to avoid performing the binding operation inside the loop.  Each call to `rbind` is duplicating and deleting the entire dataframe, taking longer and longer as it grows.  It is better to preallocate the space beforehand (if you know how many rows you'll need) or store the intermediate results in a list and then `dplyr::bind_rows()` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e!  I've tried what you suggested and it seemed to have worked, though I haven't timed the two approached yet.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could use the function `profvis::profvis()` to profile your code and see which steps are taking the most time.  If it's `getData()`, then you need more bandwidth, or to download data more efficiently; if not, then there might be room to improve your R code...

Comment: Thanks ms609!  I've actually downloaded all of the data, so there wasn't any data downloading involved in the times I quoted above.  I haven't tried timing the operations with the download yet.  So, at this point, I'm focused on trying to improve the code.  :)

Comment: @Thomas, I saw your comments above, I expected significantly more improvement.  Performing the profiling is your next option.  I'm interested in learning the results.

Comment: I tried profvis() and it ran for about 11 hours.  It still hasn't finished, and I need to leave for work, so I have to stop it.  Is it normal for it to take so long?  I have changed my code a bit, so now it normally takes a couple of hours to finish the loop.

Comment: You should profile a small subset of your data.  Optimize test again, and only then run the entire data set.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks a lot for this post. Very helpful. Would any of you know how I can be downloading Worldclim data through R at the 0.5 resolution (res=0.5), for a long list of coordinates (point data). This is quite tricky for me because I need to supply a list of lat lon coordinates of the tiles I need. But since I need tiles all over the northern hemisphere (as where my points are) it is a lot of work. Any work around this? I have looked at this post but does not really work for my situation. All the best, Kamau